# xmlstarlet how to update an attribute based on subelement value

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<star ABC="90" ABCType="Catch" endDateTime="2020-12-30T23:59:59" startDateTime="2010-08-10T06:00:00" timePeriodInDays="1" xmlns="urn:xxx:dyn:xxx:version01">    
    <tpName>seg</tpName>
    <Instance endDateTime="2016-06-08T00:01:00"   
              startDateTime="2016-06-08T00:01:00">  
        <Id>PASS1</Id>
    </Instance>
    <Instance endDateTime="2016-06-10T00:00:00"      
              startDateTime="2016-06- 08T00:01:00">
        <Id>PASS2"</Id>
    </Instance>
</star>
```

I am new to **xmlstartlet**. In the above code, I am trying to modify the **startDateTime** to **"AAAA"** of instance where **Id is PASS1**.  I tried to do the below:

```
xml ed -N w=urn:xxx:dyn:xxx:version01 -u "/w:star/w:Instance[@w:startDateTime"]/@w:startDateTime" -v "AAAA" 1.xml
```

but getting following **error**:

> None of the XPaths matched; to match a node in the default namespace
>   use '*' as the prefix (see section 5.1 in the manual). For instance,
>   use /*:node instead of /node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to prefix the attributes in your XPath.

Try this:

```
xml ed -N w=urn:xxx:dyn:xxx:version01 -u "/w:star/w:Instance[w:Id='PASS1']/@startDateTime" -v "AAAA" 1.xml
```

Output:

```
<star xmlns="urn:xxx:dyn:xxx:version01" ABC="90" ABCType="Catch" endDateTime="2020-12-30T23:59:59" startDateTime="2010-08-10T06:00:00" timePeriodInDays=
"1">
  <tpName>seg</tpName>
  <Instance endDateTime="2016-06-08T00:01:00" startDateTime="AAAA">
    <Id>PASS1</Id>
  </Instance>
  <Instance endDateTime="2016-06-10T00:00:00" startDateTime="2016-06- 08T00:01:00">
    <Id>PASS2"</Id>
  </Instance>
</star>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It works now. Thanks for teaching me that I shouldn't need to prefix the attributes in my XPath.

Comment: @seema - You're welcome. Can you please accept this answer by clicking the check mark (✅) next to it? Thanks!